# HTML/CSS need disable margin

Tags: html, css

I spent almost half hour by searching where to disable margin for submenu. Here is an examples. 
[image]

I did margin for menu links, and submenu have been affected too. BUT i dont need that. SO i cant find where to change submenu margin to be zero. You can find website in

Comment: please don't put links to live site but instead post your code and if possible narrow down your issue in a jsFiddle. Live links quickly become obsolete (as soon as you will have fixed your issue, the example won't be relevant) and thus this question would be useless for future users...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the margin from the .sub-menu li's

```
#menu ul.sub-menu li {
    margin:0;
}
```

Then change your ul ul's position with this to center the dropdown navigation. Replace your current ul style with this (line: 182 of your css).

```
#menu ul ul {
    background-color: #4d4d4d;
    display: none;
    left: 50%; /* CHANGE THE POSITION TO 50% */
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 119%;
    transform: translateX(-50%); /* THEN MOVE IT LEFT -50% OF ITS NATURAL WIDTH */
}
```

Comment: thanks you helped me a lot. Maby you know why my sub menu is in wrond positions?

Comment: Ive updated my answer for you to center the dropdown bit. @Albance

Comment: but when menu is different then that (i mean these links home .... etc) dropdown menu is still in diff place.

Comment: is it possible to make it automatic, depending from menu links

Comment: this will automatically use the native width of the dropdown and center it. `left: 50%` moves the element 50% to the right then`transform: translateX(-50%);` calculates 50% of the width of the element and moves it back on itself by 50%. ie. it's center point.

Answer (score 0):

try like this(style.css) :

```
#menu ul ul li {
    float: none;
    width: 100%; /* dont give fixed value instead give 100% */
}
```

This will remove blank space which is on hover the link

Comment: This doesn't remove the margin the OP is speaking of?

Answer (score 0):

**Reason:**
If you are using unordered list then make margin and padding for it to be zero. As there exists a default padding and margin for ul and li.

**Solution:**

```
#mainMenu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#mainMenu li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

mainmenu is the id associated with the unordered list in this example. You canremove it if you want to and apply it globally to all ul and li.

Answer (score 0):

Hey now try to this way

remove `margin-right` and define `width auto` **as like this**

```
#menu ul ul li {
  float: none;
  margin-right: 0;
  width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change in your  css

```
#menu ul li a{
width:99%;
}
```

output

[image]